# How to insert data to Open Office Base using Visual Basic?

Tags: uno, openoffice-base, openoffice-basic

I have a problem in inserting data from a sheet into database. Some people say that this can be done using (UNO) RowSet, but i find minimal example for this. Could anyone give my a sampe of this?

Open for other ways, as long it use UNO

Comment: Seems UNO is hard and not friendly. 

I will try to find another way using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it difficult to do this by using UNO, so i settling the problem by use plain SQL.